# Why my equals method is returning true for some equivalent fractions and false for others?

Tags: java, methods, equals

So I have an overridden equals method, and a program where I allow the user to input multiple integer fractions, and then check to see if 
f1(f2 - f3) = f1f2 - f1f3 . This is a necessary truth, and comes back true for *most* valid inputs. Here is my equals method:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj)
{
    if(!(obj instanceof Fraction))
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        Fraction f = (Fraction)obj;
        return top == f.top && bottom == f.bottom;
    }
}
```

and here is the tester:

```
    Fraction part1 = F1.multiply(F2.subtract(F3));
    Fraction part2a = F1.multiply(F2);
    Fraction part2b = F1.multiply(F3);
    Fraction part2 = part2a.subtract(part2b);
    System.out.println("Is f1(f2 - f3) equal to f1f2 - f1f3? " + part1.equals(part2));
    System.out.println(part1 + " ?= " + part2);
```

I also have an overridden toString method that uses a GCD method to normalize the fractions. Again, the equals check is a tautology, so it should only come back false if Object obj is not an instance of Fraction, however in the case of f1 = 3/5, f2 = 6/10, and f3 = -5/3, the answer comes back false. The test I wrote at the end there to see if they really were coming back different showed that they both amount to 34/25. So why does the equals method work for most sets of fractions but not these?

Comment: Is your implementation of `Fraction` from apache commons or do you have your own implementation?

Comment: `toString` normalizes fractions, but `equals` doesn't, you say? So do you think 68/50 equals 34/25? (I don't know if 68/50 is the actual fraction produced by this code)

Comment: What is the type of `top` and `bottom`? Perhaps int, double, BigInteger?

Comment: test 1/2 equals(2/4) return true or false?

Comment: The user could only enter int variables, otherwise an exception would be thrown. The equals method and test was one part of a much larger program with several equations, where the answer needed to be printed as a normalized fraction,which is done automatically by the `toString` method. The equals method doesn't need to print a fraction, so while in reality, 68/50 does equal 34/25, I get that this won't automatically be recognized in the program. Checking the equivalence of the cross products of the fractions, instead of the numerators and denominators themselves, solves this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix to the issue was incredibly simple, I don't know why the thought hadn't crossed my mind sooner. I simply changed the return statement from checking to see if the numerator and denominator of both fractions were equal to checking to see if the cross products of the two fractions were equal. This is the updated equals method:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj)
{
    if(!(obj instanceof Fraction))
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        Fraction f = (Fraction)obj;
        return top*f.bottom == bottom*f.top;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm assuming that `Fraction` is a class you wrote and `top` means numerator and `bottom`, denominator, and they are both primitive types, such as `int` or `float`. You will get your answer by adding a debug printout in your `equals` method -- look at the values you are comparing (not just `Fraction.toString()`).. For example, there might be a calculation error if you use floating-point arithmetic. Also, as someone pointed out in a comment, if you only reduce the fraction in a `toString` method (how?), that is not going to have an effect on the `equals` method.

Comment: Comment, not an answer.

Comment: So your answer is "apply standard debugging techniques"?

Comment: Yes, how about that? Except that it might not be obvious to OP and I explained how to do it in this case.